# Where are found report of bounce count. Kentico 9

Tags: kentico

Incorrect path to order about the total amount of bounces for the specific issue [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dfc1P.png) on this instruction
https://docs.kentico.com/k9/on-line-marketing-features/email-marketing/monitoring-bounced-campaign-emails

Tell me how to find this a report in the admin panel

Answer (score 0):

If you able to configure settings as per the given instruction in documents, then you simply need to go kentico admin panel and open Email Marketing module under Online Marketing and select the subscriber tab you will see the report for bounce email.
[image: Snapshot admin]
If you not able to view Online Marketing feature in your kentico admin then you have license edition limitation then you need to update license.

Thanks